# Can I add a button for Skype for business in my website

Tags: skype-for-business

I know its easy to add Skype link using https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons/ .
But can the similar stuff be done for SkypeForBusiness ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a link like this works with my employer.

```
<a href="SIP:user@domain.com">Chat with Skype</a>
```

I didn't see anything useful on the SDK site.

Answer (score -1):

A quick Google search for "Skype for Business button" returned many results. I don't see anything explicitly saying that you can. Have you tried to use a Skype for Business account when creating a Contact Me button? If so and it didn't work I'd say the answer is **no, the functionality isn't available.**.

Comment: You cannot use an email address with the contact me button page.

Comment: Why the downvotes - Your answer is right. Although it is poor that S4B does not allow you to do this as easily as consumer skype!

Answer (score -1):

Skype for Business has extensive set [web APIs](http://dev.office.com/skype/getting-started) available through Web SDK which you can use to achieve your functionality. Is the user on your website an anonymous user or authenticated to Skype for Business?

If the user is authenticated then you can do P2P calls through the SDK, else you would need to create meeting to let the anonymous user talk to a Skype for Business authenticated user.

Also, follow the [Web SDK sample](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk#) and check out Conversation Control that should solve your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't create a Skype Button for Skype For Business, because SFB uses email addresses as the handle, and these aren't accepted by the contact me button creator here: https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons/